# FBA user unable to login SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, forms-authentication

I have configured FBA in SharePoint 2013 as per below URL.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider/

When i try to login SharePoint portal with FBA user i am getting below Error message in SharePoint Screen.

**The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and password are correct, and then try again.**

If i look at my event viewer log i am getting below error message.

**An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated..**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Central Administration site->Manage web applications->select the relevant web application->click “User Policy” in the ribbon->add the relevant user and grant permission.

[image]